# Flicker while scrolling down in Safari

Tags: css, safari, flicker

I want to embed a Monaco Editor in a page under some fixed texts, I want the height of the Monaco Editor to fill exactly the rest of the page. People gave me an answer ([JSBin](https://jsbin.com/lafinuzezi/1/edit?html,output)):

```
<html>
    <style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .rb {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .myME {
        flex:1;
        background: grey;
    }

    #container > * {
        max-height:100%;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="rb">
            <div class="top">1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/></div>
            <div class="myME" id="container"></div>    
        </div>
    <script src="https://www.matrixlead.com/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
    <script>
        require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://www.matrixlead.com/monaco-editor/min/vs' }})

        require(["vs/editor/editor.main"], function () {
          var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
            value: 'function x() {\n\tconsole.log("Hello world!");\n}',
            language: 'javascript',
            minimap: { enabled: false },
            automaticLayout: true,
            scrollBeyondLastLine: false
          });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works in Chrome. However, in Safari, while scrolling down quickly, we could see flicker.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `overflow: auto` in this rule to fix the Safari scrolling glitch:

```
#container > * {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto; /* remove this */
}
```

Comment: Thank you... removing `overflow: auto` does fix the Safari scrolling glitch. However, we can now see a scroll bar while scrolling up and down in both Chrome and Safari. This is not what I want.

Comment: @SoftTimur Ah - I see that now. Easy fix, thankfully: add `overflow: hidden;` to your `body { }` rule at the top of the CSS.

Comment: However, in Chrome, by doing this, when you have many rows, you will see some lines are hidden in the bottom.

Comment: @SoftTimur Can you explain how you're getting that issue in Chrome? I'm not seeing it yet.

Comment: Click on the editor, then add new lines by "enter", and you will see...

Comment: I'm following your instructions but not seeing that error. All lines are visible for me in Chrome, even when my code in the Monaco Editor exceeds the page height. Testing here: https://jsbin.com/palegunapu/edit?html,output

Comment: OK. If I save the code of your last JSBin in a html file, it works well in  Chrome and Safari. Just one thing, when the code exceeds the page height, a top border appears for the editor. Can you make it always appears or never appears regardless of the code height?

Comment: @SoftTimur Cool, glad it worked. Unfortunately, the border you're talking about is built into Monaco Editor (they call it a `scroll-decoration`), and I'm not seeing any way to modify the CSS within their editor, so it most likely has to stay. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I have several questions related with bounty... I will appreciate if you could take a look...